# Teamcity and Hub integration

Tags: teamcity, jetbrains-hub

I have installed YouTrack, TeamCity, Upsource and Hub on os x. I have configured them to interact with each other.

I have installed the [TeamCity Hub Plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+Hub+Plugin) to enable the connection between teamcity and the hub, they can see each other and the users from hub have been created in teamcity.

I run into an error when I try to associate teamcity with a project I have created in the hub. I get the following error when I try to add the continuous integration service using the project wizard in the hub.

`Error: Can not create integration`

The documentation for the hub mentions setting internal properties to allow the hub dashboard to access teamcity.

The internal properties that I need to set are

```
rest.cors.optionsRequest.allowUnauthorized=true
rest.cors.origins=<dashboard hostname>
```

I have looked in the following folder

`~/.BuildServer/config`

I created a file there called `internal.properties`, entered the settings and restarted teamcity. I can confirm that teamcity can see the file because the settings are displayed in the diagnostics section at `/admin/admin.html?item=diagnostics&tab=properties`, but I still get the same error message when I try to add continuous integration to a project from the hub.

I do not have any projects in teamcity. I do not have any issues in youtrack but the project is present, it was created when I added youtrack to it using the hub. Upsource also has a project that was createad when I added it to the project from the hub.

I'm quite certain that I have followed the teamcity intructions correctly, how can I figure out what's wrong?

Am I meant to create the teamcity projects in teamcity and then link them up with the project in the hub?